# Android: Check if file already exists in MediaStore

Tags: android

I'm storing an image in the media store (to enable sharing) using the code below:

```
public static Uri storeInMediaStore(Context context, Bitmap bitmap, String title) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(Images.Media.TITLE, title);
    values.put(Images.Media.BUCKET_ID, "xxx");
    values.put(Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, "Shared via xxx");
    values.put(Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");
    Uri uri = context.getContentResolver().insert(Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
    OutputStream outstream;
    try {
        outstream = context.getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uri);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, outstream);
        outstream.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }

    return uri;
}
```

which I found in StackOverflow. This code works perfectly but the problem is, every time the user clicks the share button, I store a new image which is redundant.

What I need to do is to check if an image with this title and description already exists (title is a combination of app name, file name and date and is unique per image) and if so, simply return the existing URI and if not, create, save and then return the new Uri (which the above code is doing).

Has anyone done this before or knows how to query the media store by title and description?

Many thanks,

Comment: If your goal is to only share a Bitmap then why invoke the media store? Just save it to external memory under a self provided file name. Open a FileOutputStream instead.

Comment: @greenapps I would ideally like to also share video and audio but at the moment I'm stuck with the image part :).

Comment: You are not reacting on my comments. Why not? This does not bring you further.

Comment: @greenapps This is the only non-deprecated way to create a public file starting from Android 10.